# Access a bash array without assigning it?

Tags: bash

This works:

```
X=(foo bar)
X=${X[1]}
```

So X is now "bar". What I **want** to do is:

```
X=${(foo bar)[1]}
```

So creating an array and accessing it at the same time. One line without the intermediate step and not executing external commands. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you explain the use case a bit so we can understand better? I mean, why aren't you just doing `X="bar"` directly?

Comment: @terdon This is just the simple generic case. "foo bar" represents any value I need to split in to an array.

Comment: Could you add additional information about your usecase? It would make it easier to find an answer.

Comment: There is no additional information. What I provided is the problem that needs to be solved. I already know how to solve the problem many different ways. What I'm asking is specifically if it's possible to solve it this way.

Comment: @CR. Well, quite obviously, the answer is "no", since that is not valid syntax.

Comment: @they obviously it is not valid syntax otherwise I wouldn't ask the question. I'm trying to determine if something *like* that is possible.

Comment: I think the problem is that bash can't use expressions as values. Just a limitation in bash unless there is hack around that. I need a guru. :)

Comment: `X=$(X=(foo bar);echo ${X[1]})` is as close as I have been able to get but that executes a sub-shell plus echo... :/

Comment: The people who inherit your code will appreciate the simpler code of using a variable. I don't think what you want is possible with bash, but if you can hack something together, it won't be as readable as the simple solution.

Comment: Bash doesn't support this kind of syntax.   Perl does (e.g. `$mtime = (stat($filename))[9]` - perl's `stat()` function returns an array with 13 elements containing details about a file.  see `perldoc -f stat`).  If you're doing moderately complex string and/or array manipulations, it's well worth the effort to learn perl - it combines the features of sed, tr, awk, and much more (including the CPAN archive for library modules to do pretty much anything you can think of) into one scripting language.